# Simulating Pinch on iOS simulator with Option/Alt key

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios-simulator, pinch

Has anyone had problems with pinching in the iOS simulator on a UITableView?  I have this code:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
[self.tableView1 addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
[pinch release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
[self.tableView1 addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

in my viewDidLoad method.  In my handlePinch: and handleTap: methods, I simply NSLog(@"pinched") or @"tapped".  The tap works, but the pinching does not.  Is there a bug in the simulator, or am I not simulating it correctly for UITableView?  (hold option key for the two circles, click on the mouse, then drag to simulate pinching)

Edit: 
I selected multiTouchEnabled for the tableView and it does not recognize the pinch.  However if I change the outer container UIView and add the pinchgesture to the UIView, then it seems to work.  But I don't think that it shouldn't work if the outer UIView is not looking for the pinchgesture according to the documentation.

Comment: Make sure you start the pinch with your mouse cursor on the table view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a XIB, it's likely that `multipleTouchEnabled` is `NO`. Set it to `YES` for pinch to work.

Comment: Ah, thought that would work.  It was in fact set to NO.  However, still hasn't fixed it.  Weird...

Comment: I have tried reproducing the problem [`here`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/PinchTable.zip) but couldn't. Can you tell us what you're different here?

Comment: I just ran the project you provided.  Does yours actually say "Pinched."?  Mine will say touch when I tap.  When I hold the option key down and see the two circles, and I click and drag somewhere simulating a pinch, I do not see "Pinch." from NSLog.  Maybe I'm pinching incorrectly in the simulator?

Comment: Here's the image of the [`log`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/PinchTable.png). Are both the circles on the table view?

Comment: Ok.  I just relooked at it this morning.  I had two UITableViews.  I created one pinch gesture and added it to both tables.  When I commented out adding the pinch to the second table, it worked.  I didn't think that would be a problem.  Thanks for looking into it with me.

Comment: A gesture can be attached to one view and one view only. You will have to create a new pinch gesture for the second one. Though I think you've figured this out yourself. Good luck with your task.